# laravel 5 model class not found

Tags: laravel-5

I’m new to Laravel 5. I tried to create `Customer` model in my **Models** folder. I created both `CustomerController` and `Customer` via `php artisan make:...` and now I get the error:

> FatalErrorException in CustomerController.php line 30: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Cusomter' not found.

My `Customer` model:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model {

   //
    protected $table = 'Customer';
    protected $primaryKey = 'CID';

   // protected $fillable = [
  //    'Name',
  //    'Gender',
  //    'Address',
  //    'DiscountPercent',
  //    'Email',
  //    'Phone'
  // ];
```

}

My `CustomerController`:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\Customer;

class CustomerController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $customers = Customer::all();
        return View::make('Customer.home',compact('customers'));
        // return View('Customer.home');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

I dont know what i was doing anything wrong. Is there any help. I also did some search on Internet and i know its about namespace. Is there any ebook or documents for me to understand how namespace works, how to use and do i need to declare before using it

Comment: yes i did move this Customer.php to Models folder. i still keep two Customer.php files. One in app\Models and one in app

Comment: If they both have the namespace same namespace (`App\Models`) that might be the problem...

Comment: thanks for reminding me. i remove the Customer in app

Comment: And? did it help? (try running `composer dump-autoload` again after deleting)

Comment: yes i did. but its still stuck

Answer (score 0):

You’ve spelt “Customer” wrong in your `index` action.

Comment: thanks Martin. I fixed that. And now there is another error: 
FatalErrorException in CustomerController.php line 30:
Class 'App\Models\Customer' not found

Comment: I can’t see why it won’t load as your namespace looks alright from what you told us. Try running `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: yeah. i ran composer dump-autoload but this error is still there

Comment: Can you re-post your controller and model classes, just to ensure we’re looking at the latest versions?

Comment: * Model: 

<?php namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model {

 //
 protected $table = 'Customer';
 protected $primaryKey = 'CID';

 // protected $fillable = [
 //  'Name',
 //  'Gender',
 //  'Address',
 //  'DiscountPercent',
 //  'Email',
 //  'Phone'
 // ];

}

Comment: @user1610851 Change the namespace of your `Customer` model to match the directory: it should be `App\Models` instead of `App\Model`.

Comment: Thanks you r right Lukas. i fixed that. Now it shows me new error:
FatalErrorException in CustomerController.php line 31:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\View' not found

Comment: @user1610851 That's a different issue.. add `use View;` to import the facade from the global namespace. Or just use the `view()` helper function ;)

Comment: Thanks Martin Bean, lukasgeiter and My Do for helping me. My problems is solved. Thanks guys so much

Comment: @user1610851 Feel free to accept and up-vote an answer.

Comment: This question should be closed as the problem where just typos and it won't help anyone else...

Answer (score -2):

You should add autoload classmap in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Models"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

update composer

Comment: Thanks My Do, i already added "app/Models" in composer.json. Do i need to run some command line in terminal

Comment: I did composer dump-autoload. But the problem still exist.

Comment: Laravel auto-loads anything in the **app** directory so long as the namespaces in the files themselves are correct. This is unnecessary.

Comment: and when i update composer. There is some errors jumping out:
[RuntimeException]                                                           
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundat  
  ion\Application::getCachedCompilePath() in /home/thienvulai/laravel/example  
  /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ClearCompiledCo  
  mmand.php on line 28

Comment: In line 30 you used Cusomter::all(). It's not correct. Fix: Customer::all()